# PHP - Check if Array exists in Multidimensional Array with an Exact Match of Pair

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to check if an exact pair of two values exists in a multidimensional array together.

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
[code] => 200
[response] => Success
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => example123@sample.com
        [status] => Approved: Printed & Cleared
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => xxexample123@sample.com
        [status] => Pending
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => example1345@sample.com
        [status] => Approved
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [email] => example1235@sample.com
        [status] => Approved: Printed & Cleared
    )
)
```

Then I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
    (
        [email] => xxexample123@sample.com
        [status] => Pending
    )
```

I need to check if that exact pair exists in the multidimensional array. Not just that the status and email appear seperate from each other.

Comment: What approach have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: loop one & match against the other

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `array_search()` in the same manner if you need to get the key, but at its simplest (assuming `$array1` only has the keys and values that are being search for and in the same order):

```
$array2 = array('email'  => 'example123@sample.com',
                'status' => 'Pending');

if(in_array($array2, $array1)) {
    //yes
} else {
    //no
}
```

See the [**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/dhHtc) showing found and not found.

Comment: if arrays are just formatted as given by ThomasC, then in_array works fine, I agree (@AbraCadaver -> tested on my side, didn't try your demo but no doubt it'll do the job)